# Detect before_filter of a nonexistent action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-analysis, actioncontroller

How can I detect that I've got a `before_filter` of a non-existent action in Rails?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:kreate]

  def create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a straightup hack, but the only way I could think of checking a before filter would be on initialize. The following checks if a controller has a before/after filter that uses a non-existant action and raises an exception message if it does

```
# config/initializers/before_filters.rb

# require all controllers
Dir['app/controllers/*'].each do |path|
  require path.split('/').last if path.include? '.rb'
end

# get array of all controllers
controllers = ApplicationController.descendants

controllers.each do |controller|
  # get all filters for this controller
  filters = controller._process_action_callbacks

  # get all actions under this controller
  actions = controller.action_methods.to_a

  filters.each do |filter|
    # get all action_conditions for this filter
    action_conditions = filter.instance_variable_get(:@if)

    # raise error message if action used in filter not in available controller actions
    action_conditions.each do |action_condition|
      if actions.none? {|action| action_condition.include? action }
        message = "#{controller.name} has a #{filter.kind.to_s} filter with a non-existant action (#{action_condition.scan(/'([^']*)'/)[0][0]})"
        raise message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Thats why you need to have test cases. In this case, they would have caught it as `authorize_user` wouldn't have triggered as you applied it to a non-existent action due to a typo.